# Cross Post From StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to draw attention to the users here at Physics.SE to a question I posted in StackOverflow. It borders the line of being a pure physics question rather than a programming one, and a mathematical solution would be sufficient (as opposed to an answer with code).

I would like to know:

- Is this question on-topic for Physics.SE?
- Should I cross-post, and if so, what is the proper way of doing it?

Here's the [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31889513/890899).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Typically cross-posting is the copy-paste of your question on multiple sites (where it may or may not border on-topicness) within a short period of time (e.g., within one day). The question you have on SO is a programming question, so a direct copy-paste is obviously not going to work here and it would be quickly closed.

Your question appears to be about describing the motion of stars in a field of view as functions of x,y, so you should ask about that can be described mathematically. You *may* want to provide the SO link as a reference, but it isn't required (and probably not needed).

Note, though, that we do have a [**homework policy**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) that applies also to not-in-class-assigned-problems (and saying "This isn't homework!" doesn't help prevent closure). So you need to carefully construct your question to as to comply with the policy.

Comment: @tpg2114: good point; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange in general does not encourage cross-posting as such---pick the site you think mostly like to get a good answer and try there, then if you don't get an answer in a couple of days try another site.

And you certainly shouldn't post a non-question intended as a re-direct.

Your best bet may well be to draw attention to it in our main chat room: [the h bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).